# QtCreator/QMake on Windows Completely disable debug build

Tags: windows, qt, debugging, makefile, qt-creator

Because I've built Qt in release mode only, I don't have (and I don't need) the debug libs.
Now, I'm compiling qwt with QtCreator...

Ok, when opening the .pro for the first time (or after .pro.user deleted...), I check only the Release build (kit and tool-chain correctly configured and working).
However... When I compile, a "Makefile.debug" is created in the /src.
"Ok why not, it's automatically generated, perhaps such a makefile is always created..."

But compiling with QtCreator, this makefile is read... And compilation fails because it can't find Qt's debug libs (logic)
I've tried to explicitly pass "CONFIG -= debug_and_release" "CONFIG -= debug", but same result...

How the hell can I completely disable this "annoying" behavior ? (not to have makefile.debug generated or at less, not to link a version against Qt's debug libs)

Comment: ok, I can also pass the "release" to the make command but it is weird there is no way to disable it from qmake Oo

Answer (score 0):

Having the debug builds setup, too, does not really hurt.

But it should be possible in the .pro file. Try putting CONFIG -= debug followed by CONFIG += release there.